# Using Virtual functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, virtual

I have a small problem using virtual functions in C++

I have a class B which extends class A.

```
Class A{
  virtual function 1 // does nothing 
  virtual function 2 // does nothing
}

class B : public class A {
  function 1 { does some thing }
  function 2 { does some thing }
}
```

I have another class implement

```
class implement {

  B b;
  A *a = &B;
  a.function 1();
  a.function 2();
}
```

This code when compiled gives the following error while compiling with GCC compiler

undefined reference to function 1 and function 2.

Please help me resolve this 
thanks in advance

Comment: Real code please, this example has about 243 things wrong with it.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be related to `virtual` functions at all. Show us some compilable example code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ only pure virtual functions are allowed to exist without a function definition.
In your code you do not have any pure virtual functions. Pure virtual functions are the one's which have an `=0` in the declaration.
For example:

```
virtual void doSomething()=0;
```

The `virtual` member functions(`function1()` and `function2()`) in your base class `A` **must** have a definition since they are not pure virtual. You did not provide their definitions and hence the linker appropriately complains about missing definition.

```
undefined reference to function 1 and function 2
```